# Are there any 2 primitive pythagorean triples who share a common leg?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

So is it possible for:

$\gcd(a,b,c)=1$

$a^2+b^2=c^2$

and

$\gcd(a,d,e)=1$

$a^2+d^2=e^2$

?

Comment: I thought it was common knowledge that
$$3^2+4^2=5^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad5^2+12^2=13^2.$$

Comment: Lol i forgot about that haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any primitive Pythagorean triple can be expressed as $m^2-n^2, 2mn, m^2+n^2$ where $\gcd{m,n}=1$ and $m \not\equiv n \mod{2}$. For $m=ab, n=cd$ we can create two new quantities, $r=ac, s=bd$ such that $2mn=2rs$ and a primitive Pythagorean triple of the form $r^2-s^2, 2rs, r^2+s^2$ can be obtained which shares a common "leg" with the first triple.

Addendum: Due to the lateness of the hour, I only provided a partial answer given above to show that it was possible to answer the question in the affirmative. I glossed over a few items. Plainly $m>n$. But we must choose $(r,s)$ such that $r>s$. Accordingly, when we form $ac$ and $bd$, we must set $r$ equal to the larger of them. It will be noticed in passing that because one of $(m,n)$ and $(r,s)$ is even, that the even member of a primitive Pythagorean triple is divisible by $4$. Finally, I only demonstrated that in at least some cases, the *even* member of one primitive Pythagorean triple could appear in another. But not every even number can satisfy this condition. In particular, if $2mn=2^k$, then the only way to write factors that satisfy the general requirements is $m=2^{k-1},n=1$.

It is also usually the case that the odd member of one primitive Pythagorean triple can appear in another. One way to approach this is to factor $m^2-n^2$ into the odd factors $(m+n)(m-n)$ and examine those factors. But it is easier to employ the reasoning already presented to another formulation of primitive Pythagorean triples. $\frac{(m^2-n^2)}{2},mn,\frac{m^2+n^2}{2}$ is another formula that generates Pythagorean triples that are primitive when $\gcd{m,n}=1$ and $m \equiv n \equiv n \equiv 1 \mod{2}$. In this case, $mn$ is the smaller *odd* member of triple. As before, for $m=ab, n=cd$ we can create two new quantities, $r=ac, s=bd$ such that $mn=rs$ and a new primitive Pythagorean triple is obtained, with similar restrictions as apply in the former case. This shows that the smaller odd member of a Pythagorean triple in many instances can appear in more than one such triple. Note that if $mn=p^k$ then that particular odd number can only appear in a unique triple, analogous to the case of $2mn=2^k$ referred to above.

Comment: Thanks for catching my omission; I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: No problem! Another hint: try `\pmod` instead of `\mod`. :)

Comment: Example: (m,n)=(6,7) and (m',n')=(2,21) with Pyth. triples (84,13,85) and (84,437,445).

Answer (score 3):

We can find different triples with the same odd legs, if they exist, using this function of $(m,A)$:
$$\text{We can let }n=\sqrt{m^2-A}\text{ where m varies from }\lceil\sqrt{A}\space\rceil\text{ to }\frac{A+1}{2}$$
There is always a Pythagorean triple with side $A=(2m-1),m\in\mathbb{N}\land m\ge2$ and sometimes more than one with the same side length. The smallest of these where $A^2+B^2=C^2\land A^2+D^2=E^2$ is $A=15$ such as in $(15,8,17)$.

$$m_{min}=\lceil\sqrt{15}\space\rceil=\lceil 3.872983346\rceil=4\text{ and }m_{max}=\frac{A+1}{2}=\frac{16}{2}=8$$

Testing for $m=4\text{ to }8$, we find integers when $(m,n)=(4,1)\text{ and }(8,7)$

$$\text{For }(4,1)\quad A=4^2-1^1=15\quad B=2*4*1=8\quad C=4^2+1^2=17$$

$$\text{For }(8,7)\quad A=8^2-7^2=15\quad D=2*8*7=112\quad E=8^2+7^2=113$$
Sometimes there is only one match such as the smallest $(3,4,5)$ where $m_{min}=m_{max}=2.$ At other times, there are many matches such as for $A=105$ where $m_{min}=11$ and $m_{max}=53.$ and we find $(11,4), (13,8), (19,16),\text{ and }(53,52).$ For these respective values of $(m,n)$ we have:

$$A,B,C=105,88,137\quad D,E=208,233\quad F,G=608,617\quad H,I=5512,5513$$

Answer (score 1):

This system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&a^2+b^2=c^2\\&z^2+b^2=x^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

Solutions have the form:

$$b=4tkp^2s^2$$

$$a=2(t^2-k^2)p^2s^2$$

$$z=4k^2s^4-t^2p^4$$

$$c=2(t^2+k^2)p^2s^2$$

$$x=4k^2s^4+t^2p^4$$

$t,k,p,s$ - integers asked us.